Error "Reached maximum depth for account resolution" when the length the String parameter is too long. When its short it works fine
Im writing a test function to check if  a String passed is too long and if so it throws my custom error "NameTooLong". Everything works as expected on smaller/medium strings.  However whenthe passed String is very long I get the following error:
Error: "Error: Reached maximum depth for account resolution  at AccountsResolver.resolve"
here my test call function:
    let should_fail = "This Should Fail"
    
    let name = "Here is a name that is too long,Here is a name that is too long,Here is a name that is too long,Here is a name that is too long"
    try {
      await program.methods.initContentAccount(name, new BN(100), new BN(100)).accounts(
        {
          authority: authority.publicKey,
        }
      ).signers([authority]).rpc({commitment: 'confirmed'});
    } catch (error:any) {
      console.log(error)

      // the error thrown here is not anchor error and should be "NameTooLong"

        const err = anchor.AnchorError.parse(error.logs);
        console.log(err?.error.errorCode.code)
      assert.strictEqual(err?.error.errorCode.code, "NameTooLong");
      should_fail = "Failed"

    }
    expect(should_fail).toBe("Fail");
  })

and the rust side


pub fn initialize_content_account(ctx: Context<InitializeContentAccount>, name: String, duration: u64, cost: u64) -> Result<()> {
    // check id the name is too long
    msg!("name length: {}", name.chars().count());
    if name.chars().count() > 12 {
        msg!("Name too long");
        return err!(PayperpageError::NameTooLong);
    }
    
    //check if the cost is too low
    require!(
        cost >= COST_MIN,
        PayperpageError::CostTooLow
    );

    //save the name
    let mut data_name = [0u8; NAME_LENGTH]; //initialize array with 0s
    data_name[..name.as_bytes().len()].copy_from_slice(name.as_bytes());
    ctx.accounts.content_account.name = data_name;
    ctx.accounts.content_account.name_length = name.as_bytes().len() as u16;


    //save the cost
    ctx.accounts.content_account.cost = cost;


    //save the duration
    ctx.accounts.content_account.duration = duration;
    //save the bump
    ctx.accounts.content_account.bump = ctx.bumps.content_account;
    ctx.accounts.content_account.authority = ctx.accounts.authority.key();

    Ok(())
}

Why would the function give me this error when sending a long string, any help would be appreciated

I realized i was using the passed string ,"name" as a seed .  The seed cant be more than 32 bytes ... thats on anchor's side.
An old thread is here :
best ways to store long string as PDA seed
however the solution is dated.
